# magento 2 collection gives empty data?

Tags: magento, magento2

below is my code:

$transObj  = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction');

```
    $order_id = 9706;
    $trans_result = $transObj->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(
                    'order_id'
         ) 
         ->addAttributeToSelect(
                    'payment_id'
         )
         ->addAttributeToSelect(
                    'is_closed'
         )
         ->addAttributeToSelect(
                    'txn_id'
        )
        ->addAttributeToSelect(
                    'transaction_id'
        )
        ->addFieldToFilter(
                    'order_id',
                     array("eq" => $order_id)
        );

        var_dump($trans_result->getData());
        echo "\n Query:".$trans_result->getSelect();
```

below i am getting the out put as :

array(0) {
}

Query :SELECT `main_table`.`order_id`, `main_table`.`payment_id`, `main_table`.`is_closed`, `main_table`.`txn_id`, `main_table`.`transaction_id` FROM `sales_payment_transaction` AS `main_table` WHERE (`order_id` = 9706)

when i run the query in the Mysql , i am getting the data fetched properly.

But when i check the output of the result ($trans_result) using getData();
i am getting empty data.

Any help will be appreciated.?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have tried to see data using foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure its within the attributes. Make it simpler.

```
 $order_id = 9706;
 $trans_result = $transObj->getCollection()
                          ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => $order_id))
```

You should the same value because you're using all columns from the table, so there's no necesity to addfielters on SELECT clause. Although if you want to Select an scpecific column use

```
  $trans_result = $trans_result->addFieldToSelect('payment_id')
```

Note I'm using addFieldToSelect instead of addAttributeToSelect

Comment: Thanks a lot Leon. I have checked by using only addFieldToFilter, but still i am getting empty array.

Comment: It's a mistake from myside. It is working fine buddy. thanks for your help.

Comment: @DineshArumugam - What was the mistake